# Beginner's Profiling Qn - ASP .NET MVC + Mini-Profiler + Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: asp.net-mvc, profiling, mvc-mini-profiler

[image]

Two sections highlighted above.

---

1st - Mini-Profiler telling me how much time execution of a Controller/Action is taking (called via ajax)

**87ms**

---

2nd - Chrome Web Inspector telling me how much time the same ajax request is taking to complete

**535 ms**

---

Using glimpse, I figured that execution of the other lifecycle events (base controller / filters) took ~22ms.

Looking for guidance to figure out where the rest of the time is going.

Thanks.

---

**Edit**

This is almost consistent (variance is ~10 - 20 ms in both values - Mini-Profiler's and Chrome Inspector's).

These results are for **an online request** against a production server (VPS) running IIS 7.5. When these numbers are measured on a dev machine (localhost running IIS express), difference in Mini-Profiler and Chrome Inspector results isn't as significant.

Comment: is this consistent? does this happen when you run directly against iis as opposed to iis express or vs web server?

Answer (score 4):

Since these requests are against an online resource you need to account for the latency.

For example take this:

[image]

Server time is merely 118ms, however the dns lookup takes 598ms, connecting takes another 205ms and the response only comes back +1173ms after I visited the page. Finally the DOM only starts rendering 1.27 seconds in.

The server bits only account for time spent on the server inside your app.

You must add to that.

1. Time it takes to resolve dns.
2. Time it takes to connect (if no keepalive is in place)

[waiting time]

1. Time it takes to send the TCP packet asking for the resource
2. Overhead on the web server / proxy front end
3. Server time (the bright red number)
4. Time it takes for the first TCP packet to find its way back to you.

[/waiting time]

1. Time it takes the rest of the packets to find the way back to you. (read about TCP congestion windows)
2. Time it takes the browser to parse the stuff it gets back
3. Time it takes it render

(and then there is the interdependency of JavaScript and CSS that I am not going to touch on here)

Comment: How do I figure out the Domain Lookup and Connect durations for my ajax call? These values aren't visible through Mini-Profiler for the call.

Comment: until http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-resource-timing-20110524/ is in web browsers, getting fine grain data is not possible. you can only get that from firbug or chrome timeline, etc.

Comment: Firebug tells me that DNS Lookup and Connecting take no time at all. All of the time is spent Waiting. Does this mean that all of this time is "on the wire" time? If it also includes some "overhead" time on the web server as you mentioned, maybe there's a way to find out exactly where it's going?

Comment: @SaM it is likely it is all on-the-wire time, just ping your server, you need to add at least that time to anything you are measuring.

Comment: 250 ms to ping. So now I have ~200 ms unaccounted for (immeasurable) :) Maybe I should just let that be. I was just obsessing over whether there's anything I can do to speed this up further. There's a bit of db querying involved, so I believe 100 ms taken by the code to turn around is not bad; and the rest of the time taken - seems unavoidable, with very little scope for improvement and not terribly sub-optimal either, right?